# Rendered.enabled : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, renderer

So I am trying to see when my Renderer is deactivated so it activates so it ends the game, but the error in the title appears. Would appreciate some help! The error appears in the if statement if (Rendere.enabled==true) PS.(i know I can take the ==true out but it was to make sure).

```
private bool lost;
private MeshRenderer Rendere;    


Void Start(){
    Rendere = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    lost = false;
    Rendere.enabled = true;
}


void Update()
    {
        if (timer < Time.time) 
        {
            if (Rendere.enabled == true){
                Debug.Log("You lost");
                lost = true;
            }
    }
     }

   private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Rendere.enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Either (a) `Start` is running after `Update`, so `Rendere` never gets its value, or (b) `gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>()` is returning a null object, or (c) both.

Comment: @Amy The Start function never runs after Update, see the [execution order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

Comment: @PhilippLenssen I know it doesn't.  You just ruled out (A).

Comment: The error sounds like this particular gameObject doesn't have a meshRenderer. Can you confirm it does?

Comment: By the way, you spelled "void Start" as "Void Start", which would return an error. Can you confirm it's just in your code sample here?

Comment: Yes it is just a code sample! I checked and my cube does indeed have a MeshRenderer. The code runs has intended, but i get 500 messages of the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. It seems that only some of my cube objects were following the prefab. If you get this error make sure that they are following the main prefab or do it like me and delete all the same objects in the game and put them from the prefab again. Thanks for all the suggestions!